# Why does Octave insert this strange character on my file?

Tags: octave

I was creating the code bellow in Octave and I got some strange behaviour:

```
# Sou um lab feliz
# Jesus, nosso Senhor, te ama
S1 = single(1.0);
S2 = single(0.0);
k = 1;
while(true)
...
```

And it was looking fine for me. But when I ran the code I got this:

```
  parse error near line 1 of file 
  /home/gabriel/Documentos/Tarefas/Universidade/MS211/lab01.m
  syntax error
  ~}# Sou um lab feliz
   ^
```

These characters were not on my editor. When I opened it at VS Code they were actually there, I deleted them and everything worked fine. But when I used the Octave editor and saved the file, the same happened, every time, even in different files this happens. Why is this happening?

Comment: My guess it's related to character encoding. I don't have an answer for you, but it might be relevant to indicate which version of Octave you're on.

Comment: I'm on Octave 5.2

Comment: The problem was on the character encoding, thank you. It was configured to a bizarre enconding, when I changed to UTF-8 it stopped happening.

Comment: Why don't you post an answer explaining how you fixed this issue? It might be helpful for someone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Me and some friends, we found the problem.

For some reason I don't know, the Octave was configured to save in the HZ-GB-2312 encoding, I think that's why it was saving wrong my file, when turned to UTF-8 it started to work well, as it would be working.